# valgrind reporting invalid free /delete/ realloc

Tags: c++, valgrind

Valgrind memcheck is reporting an invalid free/delete/realloc.

Is there a way to find out where this free/delete is coming from?
I suspect this is happening some destructor.

Comment: Valgrind should give you the corresponding stack trace.

Comment: did you compile the code with debugging(-g flag) enabled?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I couldn't see any.

Comment: Post the code as well as the valgrind helpful here, so that people may help.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the valgrind options I use:

valgrind --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes

Track Origins will tell you where the free was from.